# no valid credentials (Mechanism level: failed to find any kerberos tgt) TFS 2018

Tags: gradle, tfs, configuration

I am experiencing this error when trying to pull artifact from on premise "Packages" within TFS Enterprise 2018 with gradle.
I have inserted the token as required.
I am able to push artifact by using "gradle publish" - I can see the artifact in TFS and its valid.

This error happens ONLY when doing gradle build and listing that artifact as dependency - the project is the gradle started kit .

I am guessing this is something on the server side that needs adjusting since the push is working with the same token.

Any directions towards a solution will be greatly appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: Could you share you build definition and entire build log? How's the result when you run the command locally?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I am running the gradle command locally, the TFS is installed internally and not hosted.
this is the only line that makes sense out of the enormous logs.

the build definition is single line compile("testArtifact"...)
Its a pure testing projects - the compilation is of gradle tutorial class.
I am suspecting a TFS authentication protocol definition error...

Comment: I mean how about run your project with gradle on your own machine, instead of TFS?

Comment: Not sure I understand your intention.
I am running Gradle locally but when trying to consume the artifact which is hosted on TFS i get the error.

If I am declaring the depency to be with file url somewhere on the network its Valid and the build is successful.
It seems the "Packages" feature in the TFS is not implemented correctly - or maybe a configuration issue (which the IT guys says is unlikely as TFS is auto configured).